# My proof that the real projective space $P^n$ is locally euclidean.

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I would like to show that the real projective space $P^n$ is locally homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n-1}$.

I would just like to sketch the proof before diving into details. Let $[x]$ be a linear subspace in $P^n$, then there exists at least one element $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $x \in [x]$ such that the $i$th component is equals to one.

Take an open ball $B \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ around the point $x$. 
And if we restrict the quotient map $q: \mathbb{R}^n \times\{0) \rightarrow P^n$ that defines $P^n$ and its topology to $B \cap (\mathbb{R}^{n} \cap (x \in \mathbb{R}^n |x_i = 1))$.

Then we can show that this restriction is a homeomorphism between $B \cap (\mathbb{R}^{n} \cap (x \in \mathbb{R}^n |x_i = 1))$ and its image.

Is this feasible?

I checked and I don't think anyone else used a similar proof for showing $P^n$ is a manifold, so I want to know if my strategy is valid.

thank you

Comment: This is ok if you can show that the image of your restriction is open. That follows if the quotient map is open. And it is open because $q^{-1}(q(U))=\bigcup_{\lambda\neq 0}\lambda U$. Also note that the ball $B$ has to be chosen with radius less then $1$. Otherwise you risk that $0\in B$ (btw. your quotient map should be $q:\mathbb{R}^n\backslash 0\to P^n$). An alternative (and imo a bit simplier) approach is to consider $P^n$ as the quotient of $S^n$ under antipodal points identification.

Comment: Thanks for noting the typo. However, does the radius of the ball matter? Since I am only looking at the intersection of the ball with $(\mathbb{R}^{n} \cap (x \in \mathbb{R}^n |x_i = 1))$, that shouldn't include $0$ even if it's in $B$ right?

Comment: What is your definition of $P^n$?